# Gulp minify-inline-scripts mystery error?

Tags: minify, gulp, gulp-uglify

I'm using gulp-minify-inline-scripts:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-minify-inline-scripts

I've got it in my gulp file as follows:

```
gulp.task('minify-inline', function() {
  gulp.src('www/**/*.html')
    .pipe(minifyInline())
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www'))

});
```

However, whenever I run the gulp task (even with all inline scripts removed from the site files), I get this error message and I can't figure out what the problem is:

```
{ [Error: uglify inline scripts error: Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:189:18)
    at js_error (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:197:11)
    at croak (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:656:9)
    at token_error (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:664:9)
    at unexpected (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:670:9)
    at semicolon (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:690:43)
    at simple_statement (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:864:73)
    at /Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:723:47
    at /Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:703:24
    at block_ (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:977:20)]
    message: 'uglify inline scripts error: Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:189:18)\n
        at js_error (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:197:11)\n
        at croak (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:656:9)\n
        at token_error (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:664:9)\n
        at unexpected (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:670:9)\n
        at semicolon (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:690:43)\n
        at simple_statement (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:864:73)\n
        at /Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:723:47\n
        at /Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:703:24\n
        at block_ (/Users/heather/Documents/Work/company/Web/NewSite/node_modules/gulp-minify-inline-scripts/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:977:20)',
    showStack: false,
    showProperties: true,
    plugin: 'gulp-minify-inline-scripts',
    __safety: { toString: [Function] } }
```

Comment: Have you checked your files for syntax errors?